# how to useContext in react/nextjs with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I'm new to the typescript world and I'm creating a new project in nextjs using typescript and wanted to add auth functionality with it so I'm using createContext I previously used javascript where we don't need to define default value while creating context. these are some errors I'm getting in my vscode please if someone mentors me with code it would be great.

[image]
[image]

full AuthContext.tsx

```
    import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import React from 'react'
import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";


const AuthContext = createContext();


export function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    checkUserLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  const logout = async () => {

  }

  const login = async (vals: object) => {

  }

  const register = async (vals: object) => {
 
  }

  const checkUserLoggedIn = async () => {

  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, error, register, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthContext
```

my login.tsx

```
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext'
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

const Login = () => {



  const { login, error } = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => error && toast.error(error))
```

And for the user variable, I only need
this object

```
{
   username:"ansh3453",
   id:43
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need a type you can put this on your types, I think here you need add your error and user object here:

```
export type CustomizationProps = {
    user: any, 
    error: any,
    logout: () => void;
    login: (vals: object) => void;
    register: (vals: object) => void;
    checkUserLoggedIn : () => void;
};
```

after need create the context, you can add your user and error here too, before create the context:

```
const initialState: CustomizationProps = {
    user: any, 
    error: any,
    logout: () => {},
    login: () => {},
    register: () => {},
    checkUserLoggedIn : () => {}
}; 

const ConfigContext = createContext(initialState);
```

now for your function

```
type ConfigProviderProps = {
   children: React.ReactNode;
};

export function AuthProvider({ children }: ConfigProviderProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    checkUserLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  const logout = async () => {

  }

  const login = async (vals: object) => {

  }

  const register = async (vals: object) => {
 
  }

  const checkUserLoggedIn = async () => {

  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, error, register, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthContext
```

I guess this is an example not easy to write but you should add your error and user to the type

Comment: thanks so much for your reply!, now I know the actual format for writing createContext in typescript but I'm still getting this error in vscode.

Comment: [image](https://res.cloudinary.com/appirathod/image/upload/v1661438728/AuthContext.tsx_-_chatapp_-_Visual_Studio_Code_25-08-2022_20_12_12_fwbv2h.png)

Comment: @AnshRathod do you added the user and error in the type?

Comment: I cant see your image

Comment: no I didn't add the user and error, refresh screen i added a screenshot of the image.

Comment: I update my answer try it

Comment: Wow, no errors thanks for introducing me to the right way to use context in typescript. I've been searching for answers for while. so future ref in typescript I need to define the type for context and initialize global values which are being used in context right. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is really self-descriptive:

`Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.`

`An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided`

`createContext` requires an argument that sets the default value of the Context if it ever imported outside the boundaries of a Context Provider.

Take a look at the React documentation for `createContext`: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext